# Simplesamlphp behind reverse proxy

Tags: drupal-7, simplesamlphp

I have configured my application and simplesamlphp behind reverse proxy. I have created a test SP But when I am going to test the SP, it redirects to https://web-server-ip/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=nZL instead of redirecting to ADFS server url https://adfs.server.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=nZL

I have changed the baseurlpath in config.php to "https://web-server-ip/simplesaml/". But still same error.

SP is working with App server. If I am trying to test the SP using https://app-server-ip/simplesaml, it redirects to ADFS server login.

But no luck via web server.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the the problem of reverse proxy. It is fixed now.